# Retrieving a Youtube user's playlists with PHP

Tags: php, youtube-api, playlist

Could you offer me an example about how to retrieving a Youtube user's playlists with PHP?

I have read the **[Developer's Guide: Data API Protocol – Playlists](http://code.google.com/intl/en_EN/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_playlists.html#Retrieving_playlists)**, but I didn't understood.

This is what I would like to do:

[image]

Each tab is a play list where I show the player list. In this case we're placed ino 'Porto' tab. At the right I show the videos in the list and below the player list, show the comments.

Is it possible?

Comment: What code have you got so far?

Comment: I don't have any thing yet. I don't know how to do it.

Comment: For googlers, YouTube API v2 is deprecated as of March 2015, so examples on this page don't work anymore.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
//Playlist: PLAD954BCB770DB285, remove PL from name
$playlist_id = "AD954BCB770DB285";
$url = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/".$playlist_id."?v=2&alt=json";
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url),true);
$info = $data["feed"];
$video = $info["entry"];
$nVideo = count($video);

echo "Playlist Name: ".$info["title"]['$t'].'<br/>';
echo "Number of Videos (".$nVideo."):<br/>";

for ($i = 0; $i < $nVideo; $i++){
    echo "Name: ".$video[$i]['title']['$t'].'<br/>';
    echo "Link: ".$video[$i]['link'][0]['href'].'<br/>';
    echo "Image: <img src='".$video[$i]['media$group']['media$thumbnail'][1]['url']."' /><br />";
}
```

Comment: Why do you use a number '1' in the code? Can we use another number? `echo "Image: <img src='".$video[$i]['media$group']['media$thumbnail'][1]['url']."' /><br />";`

Answer (score 2):

The newest v3 API getting [started](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started). You need a API key.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=<video_id>&key=YOUR_API_KEY&part=snippet
```

Answer (score 0):

You have got to log in first:

http://code.google.com/intl/en_EN/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_authentication.html

Comment: Which type of login are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice PHP script for Retrieving both Youtube and Vimeo user's playlists

https://github.com/greghub/youtube-vimeo-api-playlist-to-database-importer